# Recaptcha.dll not found after webpart deployment

Tags: web-part, solution-deployment, assembly-references, gac

I'm developing a webpart that contains a form for register data and send it to a list.

*I know a little about Sharepoint webpart development* but again, implementation of external resources in SharePoint customizable webparts *(not even the development using SPListItems, SPQuery, etc)* still produces me headaches...

I'm trying add recaptcha control in this webpart form, but after the deployment I check the form in runtime and I get this error:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Recaptcha, Version=1.0.5.0, PublicKeyToken=9afc4d65b28c38c2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The full error that shows me the Elements tab in Google Chromes says:

> [FileNotFoundException]: Could not load file or assembly 'Recaptcha, Version=1.0.5.0, PublicKeyToken=9afc4d65b28c38c2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
>      at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail)
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.AddAssemblyDependency(String assemblyName, Boolean addDependentAssemblies)
>      at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessTagNamespaceRegistrationCore(TagNamespaceRegisterEntry nsRegisterEntry)
>      at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive)
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
>   [HttpParseException]: Could not load file or assembly 'Recaptcha, Version=1.0.5.0, PublicKeyToken=9afc4d65b28c38c2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
>   [HttpParseException]: Could not load file or assembly 'Recaptcha, Version=1.0.5.0, PublicKeyToken=9afc4d65b28c38c2' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
>      at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
>      at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>      at Glogic.FormLiberty.FormLiberty.FormLiberty.CreateChildControls()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

The steps I follow for add the dll in GAC and SharePoint project are:

- Register the dll in GAC using Visual Studio Command Prompt.
- Add the dll directly in /bin folder.
- Add the dll in the Package folder [following the steps described in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8434215)
- Check in the manifest.xml file if the dll is already *registered*.

[In this link](http://blogs.salmanghani.info/implementing-captcha-in-sharepoint-sites/) says that the recaptcha.dll must be added in a *SafeControl* tag instead [in a *Assembly* tag](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/69917/35471):

I haven't the log files. In resumen, the main problem is:

[Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=Could%20not%20load%20file%20or%20assembly%20or%20one%20of%20its%20dependencies.%20The%20system%20cannot%20find%20the%20file%20specified)

I downloaded the recaptcha.dll [here](http://recaptcha.googlecode.com/files/recaptcha-dotnet-1.0.3.0-binary.zip)

Comment: First of all you should check Fusion log to see folder locations where .NET Framework is searching for the target assembly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SlavenSemper I'm trying to see how it works, but unfortunately I'm still searching more results and re-installing the .dll doesn't show changes... maybe the dll isn't added correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL you are trying to add is most likely a **32-bit** DLL. SharePoint development is done in **64-bit** and thus it is not possible to use that DLL in your application.

That also explains why SharePoint is not able to load your DLL since you only have the 32-bit DLL installed in your GAC after deployment.

Comment: You're right. After search and test [this code provided in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/885481/4092887) the recaptcha.dll is `I386`, _AFAIK_ that means **32-bit** for recaptcha.dll. I'm considering mark your answer as accepted, but before, can you (or anyone else) can guide about what else I can do for implement recaptcha in SharePoint?